# Интернет-магазин. Не добавляются товары. Проблема с ajax. Отладка кода

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http, отладка

При отправке формы  должны меняться два элемента в в корзине доб. цена и к-во (#korzina_2 , #korzina_3). 
Форма:

```
<form method="get" action="{PATH}product/{HREF}">
                <div class="select_block"><b>Цвета</b>
                    <select name="color" class="count">
                        {COLOR}
                    </select>
                </div><br><!-- ENDIF --><!-- IF !COLOR --><div><input type="hidden" name="color" value=""></div><!-- ENDIF -->
                <div class="select_block"><b>Количество</b>
                    <select name="num" class="count">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{HREF}"></div>
                <!--name="popupmess"-->
        <div style="position: absolute;">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 2px;">
                        <input type="button" value="Добавить в корзину" class="super button green" style="font-size: 1em;" onClick="addprice(this.form);"/></div>
            </form>
```

Функция addprice(), выбивает `alert('вышло Внутри');`:

```
   function update_k_num() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php?action=k_num",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#korzina_2").html(html);
        }
    });
}

function update_k_price() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php?action=k_price",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#korzina_3").html(html);
        }
    });
}

    function addprice(form) {
        var link = "/index.php?action=pradd&id="+form.id.value+"&num="+form.num.value+"&color="+form.color.value;
        var cont = document.getElementById('prod_cont');
        var loading = document.getElementById('loading');


        cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;
        var http = createRequestObject();
        if( http ) {
            http.open('get', link);
            http.onreadystatechange = function () { 
                if(http.readyState == 4) {
                    cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;
                    alert('вышло Внутри');
                }
            };
            http.send(null);
            update_k_num();
            update_k_price();
        } else {
            alert('Не вышло');
            document.location = link;
        }
    }
```

Php-обработчик:

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'pradd') {
    if(!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['num'])) {
        $db->conn_open();
        $id = $common->req_var('id');
        $num = $common->req_var('num');
        if($num <= '10') {
            $result = $db->q("SELECT * FROM `vedma_product` WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");
            $numrows = $db->n($result);
            if($numrows > 0) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $ses = session_id();
                $resultp = $db->q("SELECT * FROM `vedma_price` WHERE `ses_id` = '".$ses."' AND `stat` = '0'");
                $numrowsp = $db->n($resultp);
                if($numrowsp > 0) {
                    $rowp = mysql_fetch_array($resultp);
                    $price_id = $rowp['id'];
                } else {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `vedma_price` VALUES(NULL, '".$ses."', '0', '', '', '', NOW())";
                    mysql_query($sql);
                    $resultp2 = $db->q("SELECT * FROM `vedma_price` WHERE `ses_id` = '".$ses."' AND `stat` = '0'");
                    $rowp = mysql_fetch_array($resultp2);
                    $price_id = $rowp['id'];
                }
                if(empty($_GET['color']) && empty($row['color'])) {
                    $resultpa = $db->q("SELECT * FROM `vedma_price_all` WHERE `price_id` = '".$price_id."' AND `product_id` = '".$id."'");
                    $numrowspa = $db->n($resultpa);
                    if($numrowspa > 0) {
                        $rowpa = mysql_fetch_array($resultpa);
                        $num2 = $rowpa['num'] + $num;
                        $sql2 = "UPDATE `vedma_price_all` SET `num` = '".$num2."' WHERE `id` = '".$rowpa['id']."'";
                    } else {
                        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `vedma_price_all` VALUES(NULL, '".$price_id."', '".$id."', '".$num."', '')";
                    }
                    if(mysql_query($sql2)) {
                        echo messbox("Товар успешно добавлен в корзину!", "not");
                    } else {
                        echo messbox("Ошибка при добавлении!", "err");
                    }
                } else {
                    if(empty($_GET['color']) && !empty($row['color'])) {
                        echo messbox("Выберите цвет товара!", "err");
                    }
                    if(!empty($_GET['color']) && !empty($row['color'])) {
                        $color = $common->req_var('color');
                        $array_color = explode(" ", $row['color']);
                        $num_color = count($array_color);
                        for($i=0; $i<$num_color; $i++) {
                            if($array_color[$i] == $color) {
                                $color_i = "1";
                            }
                        }
                        if(!empty($color_i)) {
                            $resultpa = $db->q("SELECT * FROM `vedma_price_all` WHERE `price_id` = '".$price_id."' AND `product_id` = '".$id."' AND `color` = '".$color."'");
                            $numrowspa = $db->n($resultpa);
                            if($numrowspa > 0) {
                                $rowpa = mysql_fetch_array($resultpa);
                                $num2 = $rowpa['num'] + $num;
                                $sql2 = "UPDATE `vedma_price_all` SET `num` = '".$num2."' WHERE `id` = '".$rowpa['id']."'";
                            } else {
                                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `vedma_price_all` VALUES(NULL, '".$price_id."', '".$id."', '".$num."', '".$color."')";
                            }
                            if(mysql_query($sql2)) {
                                echo messbox("Товар успешно добавлен в корзину!", "not");
                            } else {
                                echo messbox("Ошибка при добавлении!", "err");
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo messbox("Такого цвета у товара нет!", "err");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo messbox("Такого товара не существует!", "err");
            }
        } else {
            echo messbox("Слишком большое число!", "err");
        }
        $db->conn_close();
    }
}

if($_GET['action'] == 'k_num') {
    $db->conn_open();
    echo "<center>всего товаров ".korzina("num", $ses)." ед.</center>";
    $db->conn_close();
}
if($_GET['action'] == 'k_price') {
    $db->conn_open();
    echo "<center>сумма ".korzina("price", $ses)." руб.</center>";
    $db->conn_close();
}
```

Выбивает, что все хорошо: 
echo `messbox("Товар успешно добавлен в корзину!", "not");`
GET запрос правильный, но корзина все равно не обновляется, сессия не пустая. В чем может быть проблема, помогите отладить данный код. Или хотя-бы на каком этапе, происходит сбой. Возможные ошибки. Может ли влиять изменения в .htaccess вызывать данную проблему?

Comment: А после обновления страницы корзина обновляется? Если да то проблема с БД, а если точнее то с запросом к ней. дальше думаю поймёшь что не так.

Comment: Корзина не обновляется.